# Указатель на структуру в С++

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, структуры

Я не понимаю как передается стуктура по указателю. Допустим, что есть структура:

```
typedef struct {

 char text[100];

 int value;

} console_menu;
```

И функция,которая принимает ее по указателю:

```
set_one_item(console_menu *menu) {

 sprintf(menu->text,"One item");

 menu->value=50;

}
```

Как именно она передается?

Когда функция принимает указатель,то на что он указывает ? на text или value ,или на адрес всей структуры в памяти?

Answer (score 3):

> Как именно она передается?

"Она" никак не передается. Передается не "она", а именно и только *указатель*.

В полу-формальной разговорной речи про такой способ передачи часто говорят, что "структура передается по указателю". Это нормально, но надо при этом четко понимать, что фактически передается именно и только *указатель*.

> Когда функция принимает указатель,то на что он указывает собственно?

У вас в объявлении функции ясно написано, что это указатель на структуру. Вот на такую структуру он и должен указывать.

А дальше все зависит только от вас. Какой указатель вы передали в точке вызова - такой указатель и получит функция. Он может вообще ни на что не указывать, если вы передадите в функцию null-указатель. Вы в своем примере кода не показали ни одного вызова функции.

Comment: Просто не понятно ,что значит : "Вот на такую структуру он и должен указывать.".Когда функция принимает указать на всю структуру ,то он указывает на какой-то элемент из структуры или на всю вместе?

Comment: @Вячеслав, Причем здесь вообще фраза `На всю структуру`? Указатель указывает на первый байт в памяти откуда начинает идти структура.

Comment: @LLENN Т.е если функции передается структура(первый байт в памяти откуда начинает идти структура),то  это позволяет работать со всей структурой?

Comment: @Вячеслав: На что указывает указатель - это концепция уровня языка. Да, указатель типа `console_menu *` указывает на ВСЮ структуру типа `console_menu`. Разумеется, на машинном уровне все указатели одинаковы и указывают на какую точку (байт) памяти ("начало" структуры в памяти), но на высоком (языковом) уровне указатели строго типизованы  и о них можно/лучше думать как об указывающих на ВЕСЬ объект соответствующего типа.

Comment: @Вячеслав, если кратко, то да

Answer (score 2):

Если сослаться на два источника ([раз](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)#Pointers_to_struct) и [два](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/structure-pointer)), то указатель хранит адрес всей структуры в памяти. При этом адрес первого элемента структуры совпадает с адресом самой структуры. В этом легко убедиться с помощью [простой программы](https://onlinegdb.com/H1FxkTPY4):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct SampleStruct
{
    char text[100];
    int value;
};

int main()
{
    SampleStruct *p_struct;
    std::cout << "Struct address: " << p_struct << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Struct size: " << sizeof(*p_struct) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Text address: " << &(p_struct->text) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value address: " << &(p_struct->value) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваша программа совсем не убеждает, так как содержит неопределённое поведение - разыменование неинициализированного указателя. Зато если ее доработать, то [можно убедиться в обратном - адрес первого элемента структуры может не совпадать с адресом самой структуры](http://tpcg.io/SaOnEv).

Comment: Заметьте, что если из приведённого определения структуры убрать объявление функции, то адреса структуры и первого поля будут совпадать. При этом при наличии функции разница между началом структуры и первым полем равна размеру указателя.

Comment: @VTT, несовпадение из-за наличия именно виртуальной функции, верно?

Comment: Да, потому что указатель на таблицу виртуальных функций хранится в начале объекта. Таким образом указатель на структуру совпадает с адресом указателя на таблицу виртуальных функций, который является первым элементом структуры.